# error when running .net core console application on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, raspbian

I have created an application using .net core 3.1 on visual studio 2019 (win 10). It runs very smoothly, but when I run it on my Raspberry Pi 4. It appears the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM Interop is not supported on this 
   platform.
at System.Threading.Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState state)
at NeatInput.Windows.InputSource.Listen() in C:\Users\NNG\Desktop\NeatInput- 
   develop\src\NeatInput.Windows\InputSource.cs:line 94
at NeatInput.ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\NNG\Desktop\NeatInput- 
   develop\samples\NeatInput.ConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 118
```

I tried creating a program "Hello work", publishing it and running it on Raspberry Pi, it works perfectly. This is my project.

[image]

If anyone knows the reason, please help me, thanks very much!

Comment: so you got an error that tells you there is a problem on a particular line of code.... did you look at that line of code? don't you think it might be useful to also put that code into your question?    have a look at ```Program.cs:line 118```

Comment: thanks you! I have reviewed my code, here is line 94 of file "InputSource.cs" => thread.SetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA);
line 118 in "Program.cs" => input.Listen ();
The ʻInputSource.cs` file contains the "Listen ()" function, in the "Listen ()" function there is an error command.
I don't know what the cause this error is from, can you help me?

I can't paste my code in the comments

Comment: update your question, don't paste it into the comments

Comment: the problem is,  the Apartment state, it won't be supported by raspberry pi and shouldn't need it

Comment: ok! thansk you !@@